# tool/command to know the speed of individual network connections

Tags: networking, network-monitoring

From my Ubuntu server i usually connect to different networks for codebase/builds downloads. Is it possible to monitor the speed that I get while downloading/uploading from these individual servers.
Have tried different tools available on net through forums but not much useful.

Any help would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For monitoring I use `iptraf`
With `iptraf` you can chose interface for monitoring and lock for ant session

```
sudo apt-get install iptraf
sudo iptraf
```

Chose interface and look.

Answer (score 1):

If you actually have multiple network interfaces, even tools like `ifconfig` will show you the number of bytes transferred in each of them separately.

Assuming that's not the case, and you are connecting to different servers through the same network, I recommend `ntop`. It has a web interface that allows you to list connections by IP, domain and traffic.